# How to add object to object array (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js

I've read 4 or 5 similar questions here, but can't get it to work:
I have an array of objects called *ESBegriffe*

```
 data()
   return{
          ESBegriffe: {
                        0:{"id":0,"typ": 1,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                        1:{"id":1,"typ": 1,"Kategorie": 2,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":1},
                        2:{"id":2,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                        3:{"id":3,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 2,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                        4:{"id":4,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":1},
            }
    }
```

and a method *addBegriff* to add an object to this array:

```
methods: {
  addBegriff: function(){
        var object = {5:{"id": 5,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff": "BegriffK12","Reihenfolge":1}};
        this.ESBegriffe.push(object);    
    },
}
```

activated by a button:

```
<i @click="addBegriff"> Add(+) </i>
```

but it doesn't work, on click I get the error

```
TypeError: "this.ESBegriffe.push is not a function"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: there have not a array, just i can see only objects

Comment: Maybe you add a push method? Error is correct.

Comment: @Christian Carrillo: Then I guess I better describe it as, a "collection of objects" (will update the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [1] Either you can change the way you are inserting item to the object

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    ESBegriffe: {
                          0:{"id":0,"typ": 1,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                          1:{"id":1,"typ": 1,"Kategorie": 2,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":1},
                          2:{"id":2,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                          3:{"id":3,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 2,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                          4:{"id":4,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":1},
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    addBegriff: function(){
        var object = {"id": 5,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff": "BegriffK12","Reihenfolge":1};
        
        // Push is an array prototype constructor, you can not use it with `ESBegriffe` which is an object 
        this.$set(this.ESBegriffe, 5, object); 
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <!-- // TO VIEW OBJECT CONTENT -->
  <div
    v-for="(row, i) in ESBegriffe"
    :key="i"
  >
    {{ row }}
  </div>

  <!-- YOUR BTN -->
  <i @click="addBegriff"> Add(+) </i>

</div>
```

> [2] Or you can change the object to an array to make it work

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    ESBegriffe: [
                          {"id":0,"typ": 1,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                          {"id":1,"typ": 1,"Kategorie": 2,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":1},
                          {"id":2,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                          {"id":3,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 2,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                          {"id":4,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":1},
    ]
  },
  
  methods: {
    addBegriff: function(){
        var object = {"id": 5,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff": "BegriffK12","Reihenfolge":1};
        this.ESBegriffe.push(object);    
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">

  <!-- // TO VIEW OBJECT CONTENT -->
  <div
    v-for="(row, i) in ESBegriffe"
    :key="i"
  >
    {{ row }}
  </div>

  <!-- YOUR BTN -->
  <i @click="addBegriff"> Add(+) </i>

</div>
```

Comment: @Dominic most welcome, thanks for accepting, pls upvote too if you found it helpful, this will help other users identify the right solution with ease.

Answer (score 0):

make ESBegriffe as array

```
  ESBegriffe: [
                {"id":0,"typ": 1,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                {"id":1,"typ": 1,"Kategorie": 2,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":1},
                {"id":2,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                {"id":3,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 2,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":0},
                {"id":4,"typ": 2,"Kategorie": 1,"Begriff":"foo","Reihenfolge":1},
    ]
```

then it works.

Comment: Array items cannot be key:value pairs.

Comment: Yes, typoo. I just want tell them about making it array instead of object.

Answer (score 0):

just merge the new object, replace:

`this.ESBegriffe.push(object);`

for

`this.ESBegriffe = { ...this.ESBegriffe, ...object }`